# How to keep active semantic ui's tooltip without hover?

Tags: bootstrap-4, popup, tooltip, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

i don't know what to do can you guys help me

i am trying to show semantic ui tooltip/popup without hovering on it

when i search for it so i only got was

> How to keep active semantic-ui-react tooltip without hover?

or

> How to keep active bootstrap tooltip without hover?

if you can help me pls help me
i do got the result which is wrong

```
<div id="plus1" style="width: 100%; background:pink;" data-inverted="" data-tooltip="click me" data-position="left center"></div>
```